# Pushing to git in a devcontainer that was cloned with ssh

Tags: git, ssh, vscode-devcontainer

I cloned a private repository with an ssh key. I then ran it in vscode's devcontainer. I made some changes but am unable to push changes to the remote repo. I get an error telling me that I don't have the correct key. The ssh key is stored in my linux file tree which is not on the new environment that the dev container created. How can I get my keys to be used so I can push changes?

Answer (score 0):

Add your private key to the `ssh-agent`

on your host machine...

```
ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

in your devContainer you can check to see if the credentials are available...

```
ssh-add -l
```

It will return a list of the credentials your devContainer has access to

Docs:
https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials